# Does getstream.io have its own APIs to fetch some data of interest?

Tags: api, getstream-io

Hii i am new to getstream.io. I wanted to know does getstream.io host its own APIs which can be accessed by the users developing an app using getstream.io. By APIs i mean, consider i am the user and i need information related to machine learning or some similar topic, so by using this API provided by getstream, can i fetch machine learning related info on my timeline? 
Also if there are no such APIs, are there any pre-existing feeds on getstream.io which can be accessed containing such information?

Answer (score 0):

No, our APIs do not include those kinds of features. You would need to find that information and send it to us as activity data to put into a feed.